# underscore last from scratch

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is a way to write out underscore _.last() from scratch. _.last returns the last element of an array. Passing n will return the last n elements of the array.

Please help me understand this code. What does the -n mean as a parameter of array.slice? Shouldn't it just be n, since, by definition, we'd be passing in the last n elements of the array? So why -n?

```
_.last = function(array, n) {
  if (n === 0) { 
    return [];
  }
  return n === undefined ? array[array.length -1] : array.slice(-n)
```

Comment: You can pass negative indexes to [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get elements from the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`.slice` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> As a negative index, begin indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(-2) extracts the last two elements in the sequence.

Passing `n` to `.last` is supposed to return the last `n` elements of the `array`.

As per the documentation, passing `-n` to `.slice` returns the last `n` elements of the `array`.